# Outputting first letter of last name as well as both initials in Uppercase in Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console

I'm a new student and having loads of problems with this exercise. Basically we need to write a function that gets a first and last name from the user (separated by a space) and output it into the console. We need to write 3 different functions, one to output first letter of first name original case, one first letter of last name original case, and a third output of both initials upper case. I've got the first one down but don't understand the split function well enough to get the other two it's driving me nuts. here is what i have thus far:

```
function GetText(promptMessage){
    let x = prompt(promptMessage);
    return x;
}

function Initials(FirstName, LastName){
    text = Firstname.charAt(0);
    return text;
}

text =GetText("Enter your name here");
let Firstname = text;
console.log(Initials(text));

function LastInitial(FirstName, LastName){
    var names = string.split(' ');
    return names;
}
var names;
var LastName = LastInitial(LastName);
console.log(LastName);
```

I basically have no idea how to write the second function and have just been moving the names around hoping to get it to work lol. haven't even started the Uppercase one... Please help !! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The split() method returns an array of all the elements so to target the second element just do `string.split(' ')[1]`

Below you can find the full code:

```
    function firstInitial(string) {
        return string.charAt(0);
    }

    function lastInitial(string) {
        return string.split(" ")[1].charAt(0);
    }

    function bothInitials(string) {
        return (firstInitial(string) + lastInitial(string)).toUpperCase();
    }

    let name = prompt("Enter a name");

    console.log(firstInitial(name));
    console.log(lastInitial(name));
    console.log(bothInitials(name));
```

Comment: Why not do `(firstInitial(string) + lastInitial(string)).toUppercase()`, executing `.toUppercase()` on both at the same time, making it faster and shorter?

Comment: Yup, does the same thing. Good spot.

Comment: Ahh it didn't work for me :( says "firstInitial is not defined" ....i also need to take input from the prompt box for the name so i left my GetText function on ...but yea no dice for some reason...

Comment: ohhi realized the functions were pluralized in the bottom not the top ok fixed it !! now says string.toUppercase isn't working in the 3rd function but i'll mess around with it this is still leagues ahead of where i was an hour ago haha

Comment: Sorry mate I've just fixed it. Function is toUpperCase() not toUppercase() and I am now taking a prompt

Comment: you guys rock ! i ended up figuring it out all thanks to you thanks so much